# Problems with formatting PlotLegends text

Tags: plotting, legending

To avoid issues, I post here the photo to explain you better what my problem is.

[image]

So what I would like to have, is a "correct" writings of the legend text for the Blue function. I would like it to be written as

$$x^2 - 2$$

not as

$$-2 + x^2$$

Is there a way to do it?

Thank you!

**Version: Mathematica 9**

Comment: Simply use Strings instead to avoid all issues.

Comment: By inserting your code into your question as part of an image you have created more issues than you solved. Please enter code as markdown text as instructed in site editor instructions and the site FAQ.

Comment: I don't think to know what Strings is.. Could you explain better? :/ @Sascha

Comment: Use `"x^2 - 2"` instead of `x^2 -2`

Comment: @m_goldberg I don't think so. The incriminated part of the code is clear. I just would like to have the writings $x^2 - 2$ instead of $-2 + x^2$ and the problem arises all from the part: 

Style[x^2 - 2]

Comment: @Sascha It doesn't work at all! On the contrary, the "$" do appear in the legend lol.

Oh and the strings make the think ugly when I have to use, for example, log functions or fractions with square roots..

Comment: @Sascha Also the $x^2$ with strings becomes written as x^2. Ugly to see! :/

Comment: You obviously have to type in your expression as you did before. I just didn't know how to format inside a comment. In the example you posted just wrap the equation part you want to print inside `" "`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve your problem by indicating you want "TraditionalForm" applied to your legend text. Here is a simplified example you can adapt to your needs.

```
Plot[x^2 - 2, {x, -5, 5},
  PlotStyle -> Red,
  PlotLegends -> 
    SwatchLegend[{Red}, {Style[x^2 - 2, "TraditionalForm", Bold, Red]}]]
```

[image: plot]

#### Update

In V9, you can use

```
Plot[x^2 - 2, {x, -5, 5},
  PlotStyle -> Red,
  PlotLegends -> 
    SwatchLegend[{Red}, {Style[TraditionalForm[x^2 - 2], Bold, Red]}]]
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you again M_Goldberg!!

Comment: Oh Wait... I just tried it and.. nothing! What appears in my legend is still $$-2 + x^2$$ :(

Comment: I think you have Mathematica 10. I have 9 instead..

Comment: @KimPeekII Yes, I am using V10.3 Your question didn't mention you wanted a solution for V9.

Comment: I?m sorry, sometimes I forget I have the Version 9 xD I'm used to it and I forget the other people may have the 10 one! >.<

Comment: @KimPeekII. What happens if you use `PlotLegends -> SwatchLegend[{Red}, {Style[TraditionalForm[x^2 - 2]]}]` with my example?

Comment: it works!! Thanks a lot, again!

Answer (score 1):

Just for a different approach:

```
Plot[x^2 - 2, {x, -5, 5}, PlotStyle -> Red,
 PlotLegends -> SwatchLegend[{Red},
   {PolynomialForm[x^2 - 2, TraditionalOrder -> True]}]]
```

[image]